# UrlRewrite breaks Visual Studio 2012 Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2012, url-rewrite-module

I get the following error when I try to launch the debugger in visual studio for a website project:

**Unable to start debugging on the web server.**
[Help Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28vs.debug.error.http%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29&rd=true)

I have traced the problem to a tag not being recognized in the web.config file (it has a squiggly line underneath) called  '**rewrite**'

This is used by the **URL Rewrite v2.0** module.

If I comment out the rewrite rules the debugger works perfectly.

Searching online brings up users of VS2010 with the same problem with previous versions on the ReWrite module.

The fix seems to be to downloading a file written by someone in 2009 [visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-1-1](http://ruslany.net/2009/08/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-1-1/)

Considering that file is 4 years old and we are now using VS2012 and ReWrite v2.0 I am reluctant to use it!

**Does anybody know of another fix other than having to comment out the web.config section every time we want to debug?**

***Shame on Microsoft for still not fixing this!!!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in Visual Studio 2013

Yippie!